# Error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, heroku

Busqué en todos lados y nada, no encontré ayuda y estaba testeando en heroku cli...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Node, aunque es código Javascript, está del lado del servidor, por lo que no dispone en sí mismo del DOM (`document`) que está del lado del cliente. Si quieres hacer referencia al DOM debes buscar algún modo de incluirlo en el contexto de Node, usando alguna librería por ejemplo. Para más detalles consulta [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32126003/5587982)  y sus respuestas.